# deprecated: elementor error Wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, elementor

I am new to WordPress. These are the version I am using -

```
Wordpress version: 5.7.1

Theme Name: Saasland
```

And I am receiving this error message-

> Deprecated: Elementor\Scheme_Typography is deprecated since version
> 2.8.0! Use Elementor\Core\Schemes\Typography instead. in /customers/a/a/5/test.com/httpd.www/wp-includes/functions.php on
> line 5051

And here is the code from the functions.php

```
                $replacement
            ) . $message,
            E_USER_DEPRECATED (##line 5051)
        );
    } else {
```

I have tried to google a lot but didn't manage to find any solution to this matter. Does anyone know any possible solution?

Comment: How `www/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5051` looks? Probably there is any include or somethig like that.

Comment: update elementor, it will be fixed

Comment: @pavel now you can see the code on line 5051.

Comment: @CyC0der I did update the elementor, but it didn't solve the problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Deprecated Notice is shown because of an Elementor related plugin/addon. To get rid of the message, you can find the plugin and deactivate it, you can to wait for an update of the plugin or change your setting in `wp-config.php`:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
```

OR

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );
```

Answer (score 1):

The Deprecated Notice is shown because of an Elementor related plugin/addon. To get rid of the message, you can find the plugin and deactivate it, you can to wait for an update of the plugin or change your setting in wp-config.php:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', 'true');

 
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
 
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );

@ini_set( 'display_errors', 0 );
```

Hope it will solve your issues.

Answer (score 0):

Error like this
Elementor\Scheme_Typography is deprecated since version 2.8.0! Use Elementor\Core\Schemes\Typography instead

Add use class in your PHP file like this

example:-
use Elementor\Core\Schemes\Typography as Scheme_Typography;